# Emacs24.5 for Windows 64bit TLS support

Tags: windows, 64-bit, emacs24, gnutls

I want use emacs24.5 on my windows10 64bit laptop and I want use https ,but when I download gnuutil32 from sourceforce and add all dlls into emacs installations bin directory .it does not work,somebody can tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I started to use `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip`, I had the same problem as you, I copied the `gnuutil32` dlls into emacs's bin and it doesn't work.

So I think the dlls may work on `mingw32`, I download `emacs-25.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.zip`, the `mingw32` version, **and** the `gnuutil32` dlls as well.

If you use 64bit emacs, you may find alternative 64bit dlls.